# extracting data in csv or excel form from an interactive map

Tags: csv

I'm not a programmer but i was wondering if it would be possible to extract a list of zipcodes and median income in either csv or excel form from this interactive map.
http://www.wnyc.org/story/174508-blog-census-locates-citys-wealthiest-and-poorest-neighborhoods/

Answer (score 0):

Data used from the map is coming from this website:

http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml

You can find also here some data related:

http://www.census.gov/quickfacts/map/RHI225214/36

About your map, i recommend you to find another way to extract those data, like a database or a tool available on a website, or use links provided.